# Iterate through a possibly infinite amount of nested ArrayLists

Tags: java, list

If I have a class that has a list of "sub" classes, that is instances of the same class, and this could be nested infinitely many times over, is there a way that I could loop through every list all the way down the tree?

```
public class Region {

    List<Region> subRegions = new ArrayList<Region>();

}
```

A region could have many subregions, and a subregion could have many subregions, and so on.

Comment: what is the problem.? I don't see any issue here

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here?  Print every element, find a region, or something else?

Comment: yes. There are many ways

Comment: I want to get every list of regions. So let's say there is a root region, and it has 10 subregions, and each subregion has a list of 10 subregions, and each of those has a list of 10 subregions, and so on. I want to get every Region instance within the root region.

Comment: I don't see any sub class list here. May be you are looking for `Tree` DS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [*recursive*](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java) function,

```
public void loopThrough(List<Region> regions) {
    for(Region region : regions) {
        if(region.hasSubRegion()) { 
            loopThrough(region.getSubRegions());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

**Example**

Let's add a name to your region and a recursive method that prints all names recursively.

```
public class Region {
    String name;
    List<Region> subRegions = new ArrayList<Region>();

    void printAll() {
        System.out.println(name);
        for (subRegion : subRegions) {
            subRegion.printAll(); // <-- this is recursive call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: This is an answer to the question.

Comment: You updated answer after my comment. And my comment was for your older version of post